# Different behaviors of golang tcp socket on different OS

Tags: windows, sockets, http, go

I want to simulate the http server with tcp socket written in Go. The program runs well on Linux or Mac, but has some problems on Windows. I have configured the built-in firewall to allow connections on the port. On Windows, when the browser requests the program, it shows me "This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset." Instead, it can response "Hello world" correctly on Linux or Mac. As follows.

```golang
// implement http server with tcp socket
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

var content = []byte(`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: text/plain

Hello world!`)

func handleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    conn.Write(content)
    defer conn.Close()
}

func main() {
    addr := "localhost:10000"
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    checkErr(err)
    defer listener.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            continue
        }
        go handleConn(conn)
    }
}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

I try to change some code to read all the bytes from the connection on Windows, after that, the program responses correctly.

```golang
func handleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    var buf = make([]byte, 1024)
    _, err := conn.Read(buf)
    checkErr(err)
    conn.Write(content)
    defer conn.Close()
}
```

But I don't know why must I read all the bytes of connection on Windows.

Comment: Are you sure that `localhost` points to loopback? It's generally a hostname pointing to `127.0.0.1` but in your case it may not.

Comment: My loopback address is 127.0.0.1 and localhost points to it. If localhost doesn't point to loopback, why does the new code run well?

Comment: Maybe Windows waits to finish its write before it reads your data? If you don't do things correctly don't be surprised if some things break. Also, be aware that the HTTP protocol *requires* `\r\n` as line separators. Not `\n`. Your raw byte array is clever, but not correct.

Comment: Thanks. I am not so experienced, so I doubt that is there something wrong with my code.

Comment: @WilliamA Did you try to use an HTTP utility like Postman or curl to see if they are working or is it only your browser that just doesn't work?

Comment: @Berkant I try to use postman and curl just now, they can't work.